# How to enable Application Passwords for an account in Office365 Business

Tags: passwords, office-365

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/815640/does-office365-have-app-password-option) on Superuser: Does Office365 have application passwords like Google does?

While I had my question answered about Office 365 Personal (I found that application passwords are available, and require 2-factor authentication enabled), I also learned that Office 365 for Businesses is apparently a different beast.

I haven't been able to find the correct options to enable app passwords in Office 365 for Businesses.

Given administrator permissions, how can I enable application passwords for Exchange/Office 365 for Businesses?

Reason: I'm creating my own application that uses SMTP to process emails in my business email account. Given that I don't trust anyone to program something perfectly, including myself, I'd rather not include my account password if I can instead use a password unique to that service.

[image: 365 Business Dashboard]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's hidden in plain sight, but I missed it, so the direct link is

https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/AppPasswords.aspx